# Show that $j(E^{(d)}) = j(E)$

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be given by $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ over a field $K$ and let $d \in K^\times$. The twist of $E$ by $d$ is the elliptic curve $E^{(d)}$ given by $y^2 = x^3 + Ad^2x + Bd^3$.

Show that $j(E^{(d)}) = j(E)$

I know $j(E) = 1728 \frac{4A^3}{4A^3 + 27B^2}$ and that a twist is when two different elliptic curves of the same field have the same j-invariant.

The book is super vague, but it mentions some kind of change of base where $A_1 = \mu^4A$ and $B_1 = \mu^6B$, but I don't understand it or how to apply it.

I'm completely lost, any help would be amazing.

Comment: Have you tried computing the $j$ invariant for both curves?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes, I end up with $A^3/(4A^3 + 27B^2) = A^3d^6 / 4A^3d^6 + 27B^3d^6)$

Comment: Ad those things are equal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'd say no. I know I'm wrong tho, so I don't understand how they are equal.

Comment: Well, $f/g$ is equal to $u/v$ when $fv-gu=0$...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ugh, I see it now. Im going to delete my account *sigh*

Comment: Why would you delete your account?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez shame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the result by applying the formula for $j(E)$ for the new coefficients $A' := Ad^2$ and $B' := Bd^3$.

Comment: I guess this is what I dont understand, because then arent tho only equal in that one specific case? Wouldnt any two elliptic curves be twists then if all I have to do is set $A_1$ to whatever is in front of $x$? I realize these are stupid questions, but im struggling pretty bad with this

Comment: Asyou have calculated in your comment, you can cancel the factor d^6. Just try a different example e.g. A' = d and B' = d, calculate the two j-invariants and compare the results.

Comment: @Bend omfg, I have to be the dumbest person ever. So embarrassing.